# RangeAttribute for DateTime field

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm using WCF RIA Services. I'm faced with need of RangeAttribute for DateTime field. Does RangeAttribute supports DateTime fields? Or do i need to apply own CustomAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer. It's possible to use Range attrubute for DateTime like this:

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1-Jan-1910", "1-Jan-2060", ErrorMessage = "Неверный формат даты")]
public virtual System.DateTime IssueDate
```